# "Tax of the lead" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

In this [video](http://www.amara.org/en/videos/hh7LEfpsDuxF/en/501496/) about the [TPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Pacific_Partnership) this occurs:

> If adopted, copyright enforcement measures proposed in the TPP could make the internet intimidating and repressive. Users will be afraid to view, share and interact with digital content. An early version of the tax has the lead and you should be worried about what’s inside.

I can't understand :

> "an early version of the tax has the lead"

A native guy told me "tax of the lead" means "draft of agreement" in this context. Is it true? Why?

Comment: The subtitles you copied from the video do not represent the narration accurately. Where it doesn't bear on your question I have corrected the quotation so Answerers are not confused by the ungrammatical subtitles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been misled by inaccurate subtitles, and I think you have also misunderstood your informant.

- What the narration actually says is **text**, not **tax**.

  > An early version of the **text** has the lead.
- Your informant's "draft of [the] agreement" actually represents "an early version of the text" in the original.

The expression *have the lead* means to be in the front position or have the higher score during a competition, before it is finished.

Thus the "early version of the text", which has presumably been drafted by the "big content producers" to reflect their interests, has already passed the negotiators' initial review, in secret, before any other text has been considered. Consequently, that version "has the lead" over any other version  which might reflect broader interests: it is in better position to win the "race" to determine what the final language will be.

Comment: You are right, I correct the subtitle in amara.org.

Comment: Do you mean "the lead" in this expression refers to "Big content industries"? and "An early version of the text has the lead." exactly means "in the draft of this agreement content industries has higher level"?

Comment: @ArashMousavi The "lead" is the front position in the race, which is held by the existing version. I have rewritten to try to make this clearer.